# How to get previous values from 12 rows in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report in SSRS which displays the revenue for each month:

```
    | MO-YR  | Revenue|
    |01-2019 | $10.000|
    |02-2019 | $13.000|
    |03-2019 | $9.500 |
    |...     |...     |
    |...     |...     |
    |...     |...     |
    |10-2020 | $21.000|
    |11-2020 | $850   |
```

I have to do the 3 months average and 12 months average, so for example:
For April of 2020, the 3 months average will be [(January 2020 Revenue) + (February 2020 Revenue) + (March 2020 Revenue)] / 3.
The 12 months average will be the same, but it'll have 12 months added to each other and then divided by 12. My question is: how can I somehow get values of 3 previous rows and how can I get values from 12 previous rows in SSRS?

I'm adding also the code of my dataset source, stored procedure:

```
    SELECT
        *
        FROM 
            (SELECT
            pr.company_name AS [CompanyName],
            pr.sr_service_recid AS [Ticket],
            pr.unit_price AS [Invoice Amount],
            FORMAT(ih.Date_Invoice, 'MM-yyyy') AS [MO YR],
            FORMAT(EOMONTH(ih.Date_Invoice),'dd') AS [MO Days],
            ih.Date_Invoice AS [WorkDate]
            FROM
            Product pr
            LEFT JOIN InvoiceHeader ih
                ON 
                    ih.Billing_Log_RecID = pr.Billing_Log_RecID 
                    AND 
                    ih.Company_RecID = pr.company_recid
            LEFT JOIN SRService sr 
                        ON 
                            pr.sr_service_recid = sr.SR_Service_RecID
            LEFT JOIN vService vs 
                        ON 
                            vs.SR_Service_RecID = pr.sr_service_recid
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                vt.company_name AS [CompanyName],
                vt.SR_Service_RecID AS [Ticket],
                vt.Billable_Hrs * CASE   
                    WHEN 
                        vt.Hourly_Rate < 25 
                    THEN 
                        0.00 
                    ELSE 
                        vt.Hourly_Rate 
                END [Invoice Amount],
                FORMAT(vt.Date_Start, 'MM-yyyy') AS [MO YR],
                FORMAT(EOMONTH(vt.Date_Start), 'dd') AS [MO Days],
                vt.Date_Start AS [WorkDate]
                FROM
                vTime vt
                LEFT JOIN SRService sr 
                    ON  
                        sr.SR_Service_RecID = vt.SR_Service_RecID 
                LEFT JOIN vService vs 
                    ON 
                        vs.SR_Service_RecID = vt.SR_Service_RecID
                LEFT JOIN Product pr 
                    ON 
                        pr.sr_service_recid = vt.SR_Service_RecID
                LEFT JOIN InvoiceHeader ih
                    ON 
                        vt.Invoice_Number = ih.Invoice_Number
                    )union_all
    ORDER BY [WorkDate]
```

Comment: Where is your data coming from?  This is usually something you would do in your dataset definition.

Comment: My data is coming from SQL Stored Procedure

Comment: Can you change the stored procedure or the source of the dataset?

Comment: Yes, I can do anything I want with it, but I was hoping that it can be done in srss

Comment: This will be very hard to do within SSRS without killing performance.  Can you add your procedure code to your question?

Comment: I added the code to my question!

Comment: Do you actually use the row detail in the report?  Why is this not returning aggregated data?

Comment: No, I'm not using row detail, I have got summed every month in ssrs, by using sum(invoiceamount)

Comment: This would be easier in the database, what database and version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you can do this in your dataset query then I suggest that's the best option.

To keep this answer simple I won't post the full code of the stored proc changes but it should be easy enough to do.

Step1: Add a new column to your stored proc that you can use to sort your data correctly.

```
FORMAT(vt.Date_Start, 'yyyyMM') AS [YrMoSort]
```

Step2: Dump the result of your stored proc into a temp table where we can work out the additional values required.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ([MO-YR] varchar(7), [YrMoSort] varchar(6), Revenue float)

INSERT INTO @t
    EXEC yourStoredProcNameHere

SELECT 
    *,
     MT3 = SUM(Revenue) OVER(ORDER BY YrMoSort ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW),
     MT12 = SUM(Revenue) OVER(ORDER BY YrMoSort ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW),
    FROM @t
```

**NOTE:** This assumes that there are no gaps in your data. If there are then you will need to fill those gaps before you carry out the `SUM() OVER()` part as it only looks for previous rows and has no idea that YrMoSort contains date info.